# Typo3/TCA create new tab with fields of another tab inside

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I need some help in Typo3/TCA.
Im trying to modify the backend layout of an extension, but cant get it to work.

I try to make the context of "Firma" as a new tab (see image).

[image: Firma1]

I fugured out that the context of "Firma" is defined in `tca.php` in `$TCA['tx_jobsystem_domain_model_job']` as column 'address'. (l. 328 ):

```
 'address' => array(
        'label'  => $languageFile . ':tx_jobsystem_domain_model_job.address',
        'config' => array(
            'type'           => 'inline',
            'foreign_table'  => 'tt_address',              
            #'foreign_field'  => 'uid',
            'symmetric_field' => 'address',    
            'appearance'     => array(
                'collapseAll'  => true,
                'expandSingle' => true
            )          

        )
    ),
```

I did copy it to `$TCA['tx_jobsystem_domain_model_advertisement']` at line 116 and used it at l. 272, where the tabs are defined:

```
'0' => array('showitem' => 'hidden,id, ... visits,--div--;Anzeigendetails,title,job,--div--;Firma,address;;;richtext:nowrap;'),
```

This is what i get:

[image: Firma2]

Sourcecode: `tca.php`
www.pastebin.com/a9egZsqi

also `ext_tables.php`:
www.pastebin.com/rwGbW3qG

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please better describe your problem. When you talk about line numbers, please cite them in your question and link them to the original source file (e.g. on Github). Otherwise, it is nearly impossible for others to follow your problem.

Comment: Hello StephenKing, forgot the sourcecode: Added them into the question.

Comment: Is there something I am missing? On Firma2 screenshot it seems you got it where you wanted. Are there any other fields you want to move under the Firma tab?

Comment: Yes, i want to move all fields (organisation, geschlecht, vorname ...) that belongs to Firma to the new tab. But when i move the column 'address' from line 503 to line 272, then the word "Firma" is in the new tab, but the fields are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Comments to your basic setup:**

The problem is, that you have three things here:

**A) Advertisement**

**B) A job description** *(connected to the Advertisement)*

**C) A company (Firma)** *(connected to the job)*

The relations are the following:

```
A)
---> B)
     ---> C)
```

So what you want to display C) in A) in a new tab.

Unfortunately, it would be only possible with a userFunc that handles selects the company of the job and returns as a field.

**2) Comments to your change:**

You have to change your data model like:

```
A)
---> B)
---> C)
```

You can not grab a "3rd level inline object" that is connected throught a "2nd level inline object" into the 1st level.

You second code is not working, because you do not have the connection between the `company` and the `advertisement`. For that you need to change your *ext_tables.sql* and *domains* and so on. But then you lost the connection between the `job` and the `company`.